# Error In My SQL SELECT Statement to check user exist or not

Tags: php

When I try to send  message to other user then i get message that no such user exist but actually their is user in my database i dont know where is the problem.I found this script from internet.... plz help me for this comment
//We check if the recipient is not the actual user

```
 <?php
//We check if the user is logged
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
$form = true;
$otitle = '';
$orecip = '';
$omessage = '';
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['recip'], $_POST['message']))
{
    $otitle = $_POST['title'];
    $orecip = $_POST['recip'];
    $omessage = $_POST['message'];
    //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $otitle = stripslashes($otitle);
        $orecip = stripslashes($orecip);
        $omessage = stripslashes($omessage);
    }
    //We check if all the fields are filled
    if($_POST['title']!='' and $_POST['recip']!='' and $_POST['message']!='')
    {
        //We protect the variables
        $title = mysql_real_escape_string($otitle);
        $recip = mysql_real_escape_string($orecip);
        $message = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($omessage, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
        //We check if the recipient exists
        $dn1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(id) as recip, id as recipid, (select count(*) from pm) as npm from users where username="'.$recip.'"'));
        if($dn1['recip']==1)
        {
            //We check if the recipient is not the actual user
            if($dn1['recipid']!=$_SESSION['userid'])
            {
                $id = $dn1['npm']+1;
                //We send the message
                if(mysql_query('insert into pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, timestamp, user1read, user2read)values("'.$id.'", "1", "'.$title.'", "'.$_SESSION['userid'].'", "'.$dn1['recipid'].'", "'.$message.'", "'.time().'", "yes", "no")'))
                {
?>
<div class="message">The message has successfully been sent.<br />
<a href="list_pm.php">List of my personnal messages</a></div>
<?php
                    $form = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Otherwise, we say that an error occured
                    $error = 'An error occurred while sending the message';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise, we say the user cannot send a message to himself
                $error = 'You cannot send a message to yourself.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Otherwise, we say the recipient does not exists
            $error = 'The recipient does not exists.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Otherwise, we say a field is empty
        $error = 'A field is empty. Please fill of the fields.';
    }
}
elseif(isset($_GET['recip']))
{
    //We get the username for the recipient if available
    $orecip = $_GET['recip'];
}
if($form)
{
//We display a message if necessary
if(isset($error))
{
    echo '<div class="message">'.$error.'</div>';
}
//We display the form
?>
<div class="content">
    <h1>New Personnal Message</h1>
    <form action="new_pm.php" method="post">
        Please fill the following form to send a personnal message.<br />
        <label for="title">Title</label><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($otitle, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" id="title" name="title" /><br />
        <label for="recip">Recipient<span class="small">(Username)</span></label><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($orecip, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" id="recip" name="recip" /><br />
        <label for="message">Message</label><textarea cols="40" rows="5" id="message" name="message"><?php echo htmlentities($omessage, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else
{
    echo '<div class="message">You must be logged to access this page.</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate `username` ?

Comment: no their is no duplicate username and for this i only created two users in my database

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting ?

Comment: i get this msg " The recipient does not exists. " when i try to send message to the user with selected username from the database and i have removed mysql_fetch_array from $dn1 query as it was throwing error  " Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wamp\www\pm\new_pm.php on line 44 "

Comment: Okay that explains it. Try running that query directly in ur MySQL server and there might be something wrong with that. You need need to use `mysqli_fetch_row` after running `musqli_query`.

Comment: the issue is with the count(id), it may result as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issues with your query and also the usage of `mysql` function.

Change your code from:

```
$dn1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(id) as recip, id as recipid, (select count(*) from pm) as npm from users where username="'.$recip.'"'));
```

to:

```
$query_result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS recip, 
                                    id AS recipid, 
                                    (SELECT COUNT(*) from pm) AS npm
                             FROM users 
                             WHERE username="'.$recip.'" 
                             GROUP BY id') or die(mysql_error());
$dn1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result);
```

Note: The query can be improved and also dont use `mysql_*`. They are logn gone in latest versiosn of PHP. Use `mysqli_*` instead

Comment: after replacing to your code this is the message i get and i have tried this earlier "Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause"

Comment: I think updated the query just after i posted it.. the GROUP BY is on `id` field

Comment: Yeahhhhh........... Thanks a lot Mate It Work  With Group By id Very Very Much Tnx To You

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the answer but $dn1 query has an aggregate function but it doesn't have a group by clause.